# Entity Framework is deleting an Entry

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'm fetching information from a webpage in two pages:

**First page:**
 - Content **c1** is created and a Translation **c1.t1** is created;
 - Content **c2** is created and Translation **c2.t1**  is created;

**Second page:**
 - The system detects that **c1** already exists and just adds **c1.t2** to the proper table;
 - The system detects that **c2** already exists and just adds **c2.t2** to the proper table;

Somehow, on the second page, the system is overritting **c1.t1** with **c1.t2** and only the second translation is available on the database. When debbugging, found that it is deletting **c1.t1** at some point but I couldn't figure out why.

This is my actual stuff:

- EF 4.1
- Code-First Aproach
- DbContext

I have this POCO Entities (minimized):

**RegionalContent:** - It's like a tranlation and regional info about a content:

```
public class XBLRegionalContent
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ContentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContentId")]
    public virtual XBLContent Content { get; set; }


    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string RegionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
    public virtual XBLRegion Region { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Content:** - Unique content per GUID:

```
public class XBLContent
{
    #region [ Properties ]
    /// <summary>
    /// The GUID
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [StringLength(36, ErrorMessage="Must have 36 characters")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Must have a unique GUID")]
    public string GUID { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<XBLRegionalContent> RegionalInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**Region** - Pretty straight forward:

```
public class XBLRegion
{
    [Key]
    [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage="ID must have 5 characters")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}", ErrorMessage = "ID must be in ISO 639 standard")] 
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext class has nothing different, just DbSets.

One content has many translations. One translation has one content related. The translation primary key is compound of content guid and region id.

I have a class in Model that populates the database and creates a local list that the View uses to display information. That way, I only access the Database one time to save, and don't need to retrieve information when it is saved.

Here is only the important information about this class:

```
public class XBLChart : IDisposable
{
    XBLContentContext db = new XBLContentContext();
    private string baseurl = "http://foo.bar/";

    public string Locale { get; private set; }
    public string HTML { get; private set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public ContentType Type { get; private set; }

    public List<XBLContent> Contents { get; set; }

    public XBLChart(ContentType type, string sort, string locale)
    {
        Type = type;

        if (sort == null)
            sort = Enum.GetName(typeof(SortBy), SortBy.OfferStartDate);

        if (locale != null && locale.Length == 5)
            Locale = locale;
        else
            Locale = "en-US";

        URL = baseurl + Locale + "/" + sort;
        HTML = FeedUtils.RequestHTML(URL);

        Contents = new List<XBLContent>();

        PopulateList();
    }

    private void PopulateList()
    {
        MatchCollection itens = Regexes.ChartItems().Matches(HTML);
        MatchCollection titulos = Regexes.ChartTitles().Matches(HTML);

        int type = (int)Type;
        int start = type * 12;

        this.Title = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(titulos[type].Groups["title"].Value);

        if (titulos.Count < 8 && start > 1)
        {
            start = (type - 1) * 12;
            type--;
        }

        XBLRegion region;
        if (!db.XBLRegions.Any(x => x.ID == Locale))
        {
            region = new XBLRegion { ID = Locale };
            db.XBLRegions.Add(region);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
            region = db.XBLRegions.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == Locale);


        for (int i = start; i < (start + 2); i++)
        {
            string guid = itens[i].Groups["guid"].Value;

            XBLContent c = new XBLContent(guid);
            if (!db.XBLContents.Any(x => x.GUID == guid))
            {
                c.Type = Type.ToString();
                c.PopularInfo(Locale);

                db.XBLContents.Add(c);
            }
            else
                c = db.XBLContents.Single(x => x.GUID == c.GUID);

            XBLRegionalContent regionalcontent = new XBLRegionalContent(guid, Locale);                
            if (!db.XBLRegionalInfos.Any(x => x.ContentId == guid && x.RegionId == Locale))
            {
                if (c.HTML == null)
                    c.PopularInfo(Locale);

                regionalcontent.Populate(c.HTML);
                regionalcontent.Name = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(itens[i].Groups["name"].Value);

                db.XBLRegionalInfos.Add(regionalcontent);                    
            }
            else
                regionalcontent = db.XBLRegionalInfos.Single(x => x.ContentId == guid && x.RegionId == Locale);

            db.SaveChanges();

            c.RegionalInfo.Clear();
            regionalcontent.Region = region;
            c.RegionalInfo.Add(regionalcontent);

            Contents.Add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a db.SaveChanges() after

```
db.SaveChanges();

c.RegionalInfo.Clear();
regionalcontent.Region = region;
c.RegionalInfo.Add(regionalcontent);
```